# How to programmatically call UISlider's .valueChanged event

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

When I physically touch and drag the slider, its `.valueChanged` event works fine:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged

@objc func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    print(sender.value)
}
```

I have another view that moves around, like a car on a map. When the car moves horizontally, a value is returned and that value makes the slider physically move which also works fine. But because I'm not physically dragging the slider, its `.valueChanged` doesn't get called.

How can I programmatically call the event when not touching the slider?

```
func carTraveled(distance: Double) {

    slider.value = Float(distance) // slider does move but event is never called
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call your `action` selector:

```
func carTraveled(distance: Double) {

    slider.value = Float(distance)
    sliderValueChanged(sender: slider)
}
```

Alternatively, if the slider has many target-action pairs, or you don't know the `action` selector method at that point in time, you can do [`sendActions(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618211-sendactions):

```
func carTraveled(distance: Double) {

    slider.value = Float(distance)
    slider.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, `sendActions(for:)`, I forgot about that. I always use it for buttons but I never used it for anything else. Good idea! Thanks .